# SageOne Accounts API in PHP

Tags: php, sage-one

I have found an API class (https://github.com/eddieharrison/sageone-api-php) in PHP for the SageOne Accounts Cloud Software.

I used the code found in `auth.php` with my apps CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to gain an access code.

I then tried this code (/examples/get-ledger-accounts.php):

```
define('SAGE_CLIENT_ID', 'my client id');
define('SAGE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'my client secret');

// If you do not already have an access token please see:
// /examples/auth.php
define('SAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'access code from auth.php');

$client = new SageOne(SAGE_CLIENT_ID, SAGE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessToken(SAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
$result = $client->getLedgerAccounts();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

however when testing this code, i get the following:

```
string(26) "{"error":"invalid_token"} " int(0)
Array
(
    [error] => invalid_token
)
```

Does anyone know what this means and how i can fix it to gain access to our accounts data from SageOne?

Comment: It means your `SAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` is invalid. Seems pretty clear. Generate a new one.

Comment: thanks for that - very clear indeed. ive tried regenerating it multiple times but its not working

Comment: I'd contact their support, then.

Comment: tried that too - they dont support it, just provide the documentation with responses and requests (https://developers.sageone.com/docs)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have signed up via developers.sageone.com, an `invalid_token` error is expected if you try to use the token beyond the expiration time, which is 1 hour after issuance.

Another thing I noticed is that the library you mentioned does not support the [request signing](https://developers.sageone.com/docs/en/v1#signing_your_requests) which is required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a client app or accounting integration?

I've put up a wrapper for the Sage One Accounting API v 1.1.1, which uses an Api Key instead of clientId / accessToken. This will work better if you're going for automation.

https://github.com/Sharnw/sage-one-accounting-api

API docs here: https://accounting.sageone.co.za/Marketing/DeveloperProgram.aspx